# Finding multiple regex in one string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Suppose we have this:

```
html = 'http://example.com'
regex = '<(\d{0,2})>'
regex1 = '<span>(.+?)</span>' 
p = re.compile(regex)
p1 = re.compile(regex1)
```

Is it possible to `re.findall` both `p` and `p1` within one `findall` statement?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `regex = '(<(\d{0,2})>|<span>(.+?)</span>)'` ?

Comment: Not sure this would work. I need to find both (there are always both present) and when python approaches the first one and evaluates to True then will skip the 2nd statement i guess.

Comment: Oh, I see... In that case I'm not sure as Python documentation says findall returns all non-overlapping matches. There may be a way but I don't know of one - if not, could you consider merging the two result arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You generally want to avoid using regular expressions to parse HTML. You really want to use a HTML parser instead. BeautifulSoup lets you search for elements with a certain text contained (even using regular expressions for matching specific aspects found in the HTML)

You can combine regular expressions using the `|` pipe, in a group:

```
p_or_p1 = re.compile('(?:{}|{})'.format(p, p1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the HTML parser advice. I'll surely try to learn this but until I do I'm kinda stuck with the regex at least for the current project. btw. can you recommand any worthwhile url to the HTML parser stuff except for the official documentation?

Comment: I can't recommend any BeautifulSoup tutorials because I never read one myself. :-) The documentation is pretty straightforward though; you can always look through the questions here on SO (I answered a fair number of BS questions).